# How do I fix "A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'." when running 'cordova run android'

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I am trying to build my android app and am getting an error about the version of Gradle that is being used. When I make the change that is suggested and run the command again the change gets changed back causing it to fail again.

I have tried replacing all references to `gradle-4.1-all.zip` with `gradle-4.10.1-all.zip` and for some reason it keeps getting changed back at this location `/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`

Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/user.account/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/user.account/cordovaProjects/hybrid-base/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle' line: 41
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
  >   Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.10.1. Current version is 4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/user.account/cordovaProjects/hybrid-base/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
/Users/user.account/cordovaProjects/hybrid-base/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/user.account/cordovaProjects/hybrid-base/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle' line: 41
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
  >   Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.10.1. Current version is 4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/user.account/cordovaProjects/hybrid-base/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s

I am able to get a build to work if I do a `cordova platform remove android` and then immediately `cordova platform add android` but as soon as I try to build a second time it fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for any reason you need a different version of gradle there is no need to edit any file, just set the CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL env var with value the url where to fin the gradle zip, for example

```
http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

I do not have any problem with version 4.1 ( win10, android platform 7.1.4 ).

After you set your desired gradle version, reset your project ( remove all plugin and all platforms and manual edits then reinstall ) and then try to build.

If the problem persist, to help you better, post the error and please specify which OS, cordova version and android platform version you are using.

As a rule of thumb, from my experience with cordova, when you think that the only way to set a certain configuration is to edit platform files, there is probably a proper way to do so ( for example to automatically sign the apk when build )

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you help me understand your answer better? Where is `CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL` env_var located?

I am on 
OS: High Sierra 10.13.6
Cordova: 8.1.2
Android: 7.1.4

Comment: I googled it, this post can help you https://medium.com/@himanshuagarwal1395/setting-up-environment-variables-in-macos-sierra-f5978369b255